# scrapy pipeline exporter object is not getting instantiated

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using scrapy to parse a table containing links and save it in json. The links from table contain additional detail and they will be fetched and stored into another json. (following this example: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html)

To achieve this I am using a pipeline to check item type and store result in appropriate json. However, I am stuck in some weird error. Please refer below:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter
from for_icu import items

class ListPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.files = {}

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    pipeline = cls()
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
    crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    return pipeline

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    print("spider_opened")
    file_table = open('%s_table.json' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.files[spider].append(file_table)
    self.exporter1 = JsonItemExporter(file_table)
    self.exporter1.start_exporting()
    file_detail = open('%s_detail.json' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.files[spider].append(file_detail)
    self.exporter2 = JsonItemExporter(file_detail)
    self.exporter2.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    print("spider_closed")
    self.exporter1.finish_exporting()
    self.exporter2.finish_exporting()
    for file in self.files.pop(spider):
        file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print("process_item")
    if isinstance(item, items.UniListItem):
        self.exporter1.export_item(item)
        return item
    elif isinstance(item, items.UniDetail):
        self.exporter22.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Error:

```
    2017-12-27 11:41:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'country': ('Finland',),
 'country_code': ('fi ',),
 'u_link': ('http://www.xxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx.htm',),
 'u': (' pisto',)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/website_scrapy/for_icu/for_icu/pipelines.py", line 31, in process_item
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
AttributeError: 'ListPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter1'
```

Please let me know what I am missing here... being stuck at this from past couple of hours ...

Comment: put `print()` in methods and see which ones are executed. Why do you use `spider_opened` ? Can't you use `'open_spider'` as in [examples](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) ?

Comment: um yes, you are right, dispatcher and those methods are depricated. I changed the methods to the ones mentioned in examples. and I can see the outputs that I printed using `print()`

however, please refer below I want to open two files and want write respective item objects but I am now getting errors ... `pipeline object has no attribute files` and `pipeline object has no attribute exporter1`. Posting the modified code above

Comment: You need to add `self.exporter1 = None` in `__init__`

Comment: Thanks Tarun, that makes class aware of exporter1 as its member but now output is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'export_item'`

why `JsonItemExporter(file_table)` is not working and giving exporte object?

Comment: I still don't know why you use `spider_opened` if you can use `'open_spider'` (as in example) to open two files.

Comment: because of example here : https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html
and what is the difference between `spider_opend` and `open_spider` ... a sequence when called?

Comment: as for me `open_spider` is built-in method which is always executed, `spider_opened` is not bult-in method and it will not work if you don't use signals. You can even use different name (ie. `hello_world`) but you have to use signals to assign it to event. Probably after assigning both works the same way but I never checkrd this.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to have exporter work, so I used simple filewriter for the task:

```
class ListPipeline(object):
unilist = []
unidetail = []

def close_spider(self, spider):
    print("spider_closed")
    file_table = open('%s_table.json' % spider.name, 'w')
    line = json.dumps(self.unilist)
    file_table.write(line)
    file_table.close()
    file_detail = open('%s_detail.json' % spider.name, 'w')
    line = json.dumps(self.unidetail)
    file_detail.write(line)
    file_detail.close()
    self.unilist.clear()
    self.unidetail.clear()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print("process_item")
    if isinstance(item, items.UniListItem):
        self.unilist.append(dict((item)))
        return item
    elif isinstance(item, items.UniDetail):
        self.unidetail.append(dict((item)))
        return item
```

This makes me achieve what I want but it would be better if one can use builtin exporters. If someone knows how to make it work, please update.